# Start various dynamically processes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, process

I'd like to generate a dynamically threads or processes in Python to consume each own queue.

My code: main.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from classes import roi_process
import time
import os
import copy
import queue
import multiprocessing

roi_list = eval("[(0,0,639,720,1),(640,0,1280,720,2)]")

for _ROI in roi_list:
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + str(_ROI[4]))
    vars()["FILA_"+str(_ROI[4])] = queue.Queue(maxsize=4)
    vars()["T_"+str(_ROI[4])] = multiprocessing.Process(target = roi_process.RoiProcess, args = ( eval("FILA_"+str(_ROI[4])) , str(_ROI[4])), daemon=True)


for _ROI in roi_list:
    eval("T_"+str(_ROI[4])).start()
```

classes/roi_process.py

```
import cv2
import queue
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import os

class RoiProcess:
    def __init__(self, queue_pool = None, id_roi = 0):
        self.id_roi = id_roi
        self.queue_pool = queue_pool
        print("Iniciou em thread o id: " + self.id_roi)
        self.run()


    def run(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            print(str(self.id_roi) + ": " + str(i))
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

This is generating the following error:

```
(tensorflow) C:\projects\car detector\semparar\AI_CARANDPLATE>python main.py
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 1
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    eval("T_"+str(_ROI[4])).start()
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

(tensorflow) C:\projects\car detector\semparar\AI_CARANDPLATE>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Users\MasterRoot\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado
```

I really need to start dynamic threads or processes to consume every each poll that will be fed by a `while True:` in `main.py`

I will make a opencv frame reader and slice the main frame into many pieces.
After that I will feed a dynamic queue object with this information and each thread will process a predictor as I need.

I changed my code to:

```
FILA={}
T={}
#cria fila para cada ROI e instancia uma thread de obj para ler esta fila continuamente.
for _ROI in roi_list:
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + str(_ROI[4]))
    FILA[_ROI[4]] = queue.Queue(maxsize=4)
    T[_ROI[4]] = multiprocessing.Process(target = roi_process.RoiProcess, args = ( FILA[_ROI[4]] , str(_ROI[4])), daemon=True).start()
```

but its keepeing going to do the same error for threads.

Comment: `vars()["FILA_"+str(_ROI[4])] = queue.Queue(maxsize=4)` don't do this. Use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`, **don't dynamically create variables**. Python is not bash, get out of the habit of dynamically generating code strings then execute them.

Comment: could you do me a example? in a beginner in python.

Comment: Sure, `roi_list = eval("[(0,0,639,720,1),(640,0,1280,720,2)]")` is insane. You use `roi_list = [(0,0,639,720,1),(640,0,1280,720,2)]`. Instead of `vars()["FILA_"+str(_ROI[4])]` use a `dict`, `FILAS  = {}` then use `FILAS[_ROI[4]]` etc

Comment: Don't use `eval`. If you are a beginner, there is essentially no good reason for you to use it. Dynamic code executing is for people who are doing specialized things, like building a debugger etc, unless you are doing that, your code should almost certainly be free of `eval` or introspecting `vars()`, `globals()`, `locals()` etc

Comment: ANYWAY the issue here, I think, is that you can't pickle `queue.Queue(maxsize=4)` objects. Because they contain `'_thread.lock'` objects, which are unpickleable, and multiprocessing uses `pickle` for interprocess communication.

Comment: do you know how to fix it?

Comment: i posted my changes

Answer (score 0):

Don't use standard `Queue` with multiprocessing, use:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```